# Loading data from one Dictionary into another

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to update data. From input data converted to same structure from one dictionary into another dictionary, my already existing data.

Pseudo code:

```
Dictionary<foo, bar> originalData; // Count = 128
Dictionary<foo, bar> inputData; // Count = 112
```

I could just write the following code:

```
foreach (var key in originalData.Keys)
{
    if (inputData.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        originalData[key] = inputData[key];
    }
}
```

But of course this will produce the following error:

> "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

What is the best way to handle this operation?

Comment: Have you tried `foreach (var key in originalData.Keys.ToList())`?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do this the other way around?

Comment: @wkl Yeah I already did the .ToList(), it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start from the other end: rather than iterating `originalData`, iterate `inputData`:

```
foreach (var pair in inputData) {
    if (originalData.ContainsKey(pair.Key)) {
        originalData[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
    }
}
```

Note that by iterating key-value pairs you avoid the second look-up into `inputData`.

You can go further, and convert `if` to LINQ:

```
foreach (var pair in inputData.Where(p => originalData.ContainsKey(p.Key))) {
    originalData[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
}
```

Comment: I like your LINQ answer! I will actually use that in my code!

Answer (score 3):

Why not turn around the iterator? It is safe since you test the keys to exist in both dictionaries.

```
foreach (var key in inputData.Keys)
{
    if (originalData.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        originalData[key] = inputData[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are modifying the collection you are iterating. You can use LINQ `ToArray` to iterate on a copy of your keys and avoid your problem:

```
foreach (var key in originalData.Keys.ToArray())
{
    if (inputData.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        originalData[key] = inputData[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not very efficient... The other answers don't expect you to create a new array. What if there are 1000 items in there? Are you going to create an array for just that?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes, I am creating an array for just that. Modifying the collection you are iterating is a common problem and you can not just turn around iteration like that. In these cases you _need to_ iterate on a copy of the keys. I've done this often and efficiency never became an issue.

Comment: But not in this case.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: It depends on what matters for you. If iterating the `originalData` makes the code more understandable because it is closer to the domain problem you are solving, this is the preferrable solution. Efficiency is only one of many aspects that matter and it is silly to put it above everything else no matter what.

Comment: To improve readability of the code, I put this in a separate method with appropriate naming and a small comment.